# Get Data from SQLite which is placed on SDCard

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sdcard

I want to create an android application which get data from sqlite database placed on my sdcard directory.

can anyone give me a tutorial or a link that 100% works?

I've search for the tutorial, but they just give the way to copy from /data/data/package/databases to /sdcard

thanks before, sorry for the english.

Comment: [Using your own SQLite database in Android applications](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/) You mean this tutorial?

Comment: it means, I put my sqlite file on assets dir, and copy it to sdcard?
cmiiw, it will make the application has a bigger memory on internal storage?

Comment: I did not try it on sdcard, you may be able to change the path and connect to sdcard directly. But I am pretty sure that you can copy it to  `assets` folder of your project from sdcard, and everything 100% works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This blog](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/) describes how to add an sqlite database to your apk and then copy it to data/data/... You could use the copying part to copy the database from sdcard instead of the assets directory used in the blog article.

Comment: thanks to respon,

i think it will consumes internal storage, isn't it?

Comment: yes, the article is about copying from internal storage to the data/data/... area but I think it should work the same for sd-card, only with other path.